# problem with sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
;with cte as
( 
  select FingerId, [Date],
         LogTime,
         row_number() over(partition by FingerId order by LogTime) as rn
  from InOut 
)
select C3.EmployeeName,C1.FingerId,
       C1.LogTime as InTime,
       C2.LogTime as OutTime,
       C2.[Date]
from cte as C1
  left outer join cte as C2
    on C1.FingerId = C2.FingerId and
       C1.rn + 1 = C2.rn INNER JOIN
           EmployeeMaster as C3 ON C3.Fingerid = C2.Fingerid
where C1.rn % 2 = 1 and  C3.EmployeeName = 'xyz' and C1.[Date] between '2011-07-21' and '2011-07-29' order by C2.[Date]

select * From Inout order by LogTime asc
```

I am having INOUT Table **It have 5 record and 3 record is of 2011-07-2011**

InOuT Table:

```
AutoId     FingerId      LogTime            Date
1            22          11:18:48 AM       2011-07-29
2            22          11:19:54 AM       2011-07-29
3            22          11:20:50 AM       2011-07-21
4            22          11:21:54 AM       2011-07-21
5            22          11:21:59 AM       2011-07-21
```

I am getting this output by this above query

```
EmployeeName  FingerId   InTime         OutTime        Date

xyz             22        11:20:50 AM    11:21:54 AM   2011-07-21 
xyz             22        11:18:48 AM    11:19:54 AM   2011-07-29
```

**I Want this type of OutPut:-**

```
EmployeeName  FingerId   InTime         OutTime        Date

xyz             22        11:20:50 AM    11:21:54 AM   2011-07-21
xyz             22        11:21:59 AM    ----          2011-07-21  
xyz             22        11:18:48 AM    11:19:54 AM   2011-07-29
```

Here 2nd row is having InTime and i want outtime should display "---" dash.But i m not getting with this query. Query is correct but need to do modify for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some modifications to your query which I'm posting now with the changes highlighted in bold:

```
;WITH cte AS
( 
  SELECT FingerId, [Date],
         LogTime,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FingerId ORDER BY LogTime) AS rn
  FROM InOut 
)
SELECT C3.EmployeeName,C1.FingerId,
       C1.LogTime AS InTime,
       C2.LogTime AS OutTime,
       COALESCE(C2.[Date], C1.[Date]) AS Date
FROM cte AS C1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cte AS C2 ON C1.FingerId = C2.FingerId AND C1.rn + 1 = C2.rn
  INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster AS C3 ON C3.Fingerid = C1.Fingerid
WHERE C1.rn % 2 = 1
  AND C3.EmployeeName = 'xyz'
  AND C1.[Date] BETWEEN '2011-07-21' AND '2011-07-29'
ORDER BY C1.[Date]
```

Originally I was thinking about changing `C1.[Date]` in the SELECT clause to `C2.[Date]`, but then I wasn't sure it would be quite adequate a replacement in case the two dates were different. You can see for yourself which option is better, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use C1.[Date] instead of C2.[Date] in your WHERE clause - since you are outer joining to C2 and the row you are missing has a NULL value for C2.[Date].

Comment: but still i m not get that output which i want if i use "C1.[Date] instead of C2.[Date] in your WHERE clause"